# jquery animation really laggy in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

When animating the height of my nav, it's extremely laggy in Safari. Works fine in Chrome. Done research and cannot find any relevant fixes.

Here is my jQuery code if it helps!

```js
var navh = $('nav ul').height();

$('span').click(function()
{
    if(navh < 225)
    {
        $('nav ul').stop().animate(
        {
            height: "225px"
        }, "1500");

        navh = 225;
        return false;
    }
    else if(navh > 0)
    {
        $('nav ul').stop().animate(
        {
            height: "0px"
        }, "1500");

        navh = 0;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Someone recommended adding `.stop()` however this hasn't solved it.

Cheers,

Patrick

Comment: We need your HTML, CSS and jQuery - a reproducible example so we can see the bug in action. If you want smooth animations, you might want to avoid jQuery `.animate` - you're only animating on CSS `height` so native CSS `transition` would be able to do this with no lag.

Comment: I ran an experiment at university where I compared Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari animations on a canvas to see how many objects they could each handle and at what frame rate. Safari was by far the worst, stuttering at only a couple hundred objects on the canvas (compared to chrome that performed the same with over 3000). Depending on what version of Safari you are targeting, I'd back Jon Uleis and suggest native CSS transitions.

Comment: Would you suggest doing this by toggling a class via jQuery?

Comment: Just tried it using `.toggleClass` and using transitions on the classes, still very laggy and choppy.